# how to save multiple input and files using ajax and laravel 5.6

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5.6

I have about twenty `text-box`, `checkbox` and `select` as well as four file type inputs. I would like to save the input to a database using Laravel and AJAX.

Actually, I can save all inputs **except** file type (images).

**Table:** `META | VALUE`

**My route:** `$this::resource('/settings','SettingController')->only(['index', 'store']);`

**Controller:**

```
$setting = $request->all();
foreach ($setting as $meta => $value) {
    $SF = new Setting();
    $SF->meta = $meta;
    $SF->value = $value;
    echo  $SF->save();
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
 <input type="text" name="site_title"  id="site-title">
 <input type="checkbox" name="register"  id="register">
  ....
 <input type="file" name="logo"  id="logo">
 <input type="file" name="favicon"  id="favicon">
 <input type="file" name="user_profile"  id="user_profile">
 <input type="file" name="Personal"  id="Personal">
```

**AJAX code:**

```
 $('#setting-forms').on('submit', function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    let _token =  $('input[name=_token]').val();  //Get Token
    let FormInputs = $("#setting-forms").serialize(); 

    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/settings',
        data: FormInputs ,

        success: function (data) {
          //Some Success MSG

        },
        error: function () {
             //Some Error MSG
        },
    });
```

Now, this code saves all inputs except file types and my result is something like this :

```
     META     |     VALUE
--------------+--------------
   site_title |   Laravel
    register  |     On
      ....    |     ...
```

But I want save all image files too, so I changed my AJAX code to the following:

```
 let formData = new FormData();
 let logo = $("#logo")[0].files[0];
 formData.append('logo', logo);
 formData.append('FormInputs', FormInputs);
 $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/settings',
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': _token
        },
```

Now I can save logos but my text is all saved on a single row. I get this:

```
     META     |                Value
--------------+-----------------------------------
     Logo     |               MyLOGO
   FormInputs |  site_title=titlea&register=on&...
```

While I would like something like that:

```
     META     |     VALUE
--------------+--------------
    Logo      |    MyLOGO
  site_title  |    title
   register   |     On
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,After 3 day finally get my answer. So, I put my code here if anybody needed or have my problem.

Above code is work just need some changes and here changes.

```
//let FormInputs = $("#setting-forms").serialize();  
  let FormInputs = $("#setting-forms").serializeArray();

 // formData.append('FormInputs', FormInputs);
 jQuery.each(FormInputs, function (i, field) {
        formData.append(field.name, field.value);
 });
```

Well, Now work fine.